# Why does difftime() result in different result when using mktime handling pointer and non-pointer?

Tags: c++, c, mktime, time.h

I try to use

```
    difftime(time_t end, time_t mktime(start) )
```

to calculate the difference between two different time in two different ways. Just for curiosity！And I found it results in different results, failure and success. I don't know why it happened?

Why does it result in different results in two cases as following?

```
    // Failure Case 1     when execution, segmentation fault
    time_t end;
    time(&end);

    struct tm * start;   // defining a pointer

    start->tm_hour = 0;
    start->tm_min  = 0;
    start->tm_sec  = 0;
    start->tm_year = 114;
    start->tm_mon  = 6;
    start->tm_mday = 29;

    double second = difftime(end, mktime(start) ); // where problem come from!

    // Success Case 2, with expected result
    time_t end;
    time(&end);       

    struct tm start;   // defining a non-pointer

    start.tm_hour = 0;
    start.tm_min  = 0;
    start.tm_sec  = 0;
    start.tm_year = 114;
    start.tm_mon  = 6;
    start.tm_mday = 29;

    double second = difftime(end, mktime( &start) );
```

Comment: You're assigning data through an indeterminate pointer (`struct tm *start;`), invoking *undefined behavior* in doing so.

Comment: You forgot to allocate memory to *start

Comment: @TomásBadan how to allocate memory in this case?

Comment: You can use malloc: start = malloc(sizeof(*start));

Comment: Even so, you may get different results due to uninitialized fields in the `tm` structure. E.g `struct tm start = {};` (the word `struct` is optionial in C++, required in C) or `tm *start = new tm();` [C++] or `struct tm *start = calloc(1, sizeof(tm));` [C]

Comment: Hi @MatsPetersson, which way would you prefer in my case? Because when I define pointer of struct tm *, it alway display wrong answer, which is 1 hour difference.

Comment: Depends on the actual language you use and what you are trying to achieve. Allocating small data structures from the heap is generally not a good idea in the first place, so should be avoided, use "Case 2" of your code, but add `= {}` to guarantee that the `tm` structure is filled with zero value [and you can then remove the `= 0` for hour, min and sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original case 1 doesn't allocate memory, and both cases do not clear ALL the fields in the `tm` structure, which may be required to get the correct result (and certainly is a "good practice").

To solve Case 1 in C, the best solution is to use `calloc`:

```
struct tm *start = calloc(1, sizeof(struct tm)); 

start->tm_year = 114;
start->tm_mon  = 6;
start->tm_mday = 29;
```

and then when you no longer need the `start` value, use

```
free(start);
```

(Note that since the structure is filled with zeros, you no longer need to manually set hour, min, sec)

In C++, you'd use `new` instead:

```
tm *start = new tm(); 
...
// After it is finished. 
delete start
```

The empty parenthesis in `tm()` makes it "fill with zero values" after allocating the actual memory.

The "Case 2" variant is preferred, since it allocates the `start` variable on the stack.

Case 1 are somewhat bad, since allocating memory for small data structures (small typically means anything smaller than around 1KB, but it depends on the actual runtime environment, a watch with 64KB of RAM may have stricter requirements than a desktop machine with 16GB of RAM, and a mobile phone would be somewhere in between those, somewhat depending on what kind of phone it is). There are at least two reasons to avoid "small" memory allocations:

1. It takes more memory, since all known allocators use SOME extra memory to keep track of the actual "lump" of memory allocated.
2. It takes extra time because `new` or `calloc` are much more complex than the allocation on the stack (in typical machines, allocating space on the stack takes 1-2 instructions above and beyond the same function with no variables at all, where a call to `new` or `{c,m}alloc` can be half a dozen just for the call and the same again for `delete` or `free`, and several dozen to a few thousand instructions inside those library functions - how long the code is depends largely on how it is implemented, and whether the runtime has some "memory available" or a call into the OS is required to "get some more memory" as well). And of course, you need to keep track of the allocation and not "leak" it. [There are C++ solutions to do that too, but I've written enough in this answer already to make it hard to follow]

For case 2 you can use:

```
struct tm start = {};
```

(And again, you don't need to set zero-values for hour, min and sec)

In C++ it is correct to omit `struct`, since `struct tm { ... };` declaration in the relevant header file makes the name `tm` represent the structure anyway - this applies for all `struct` and `class` names - only exception is if the same name is used in a different way, e.g. there's a function or variable called `tm` in the same context - in which case the compiler will give some error saying "don't understand what you mean by `tm` here" [exact wording varies depending on which compiler is used].

Since the original question specifies BOTH C and C++, I've tried to explain

Comment: The second variant in C++ is strongly preferred. Avoid new wherever possible. Then you can't forget to delete.

Comment: @MatsPeersson Your answer is very clear. Thank you very much. However, no matter either way, the variable "start" increases by 1 hour after line " second = difftime(end, mktime(&start) ); "  I have no idea why.

Comment: @MatsPeersson I know where is my result come from. I never assign a meaningful value to member "tm_isdst". mktime() thus uses an indeterminate value and the consequence is undefined behaviour.